# How to replace Ubuntu with Mint

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, dual-boot

Since Ubuntu and Linux Mint are using the same package manager, I would like to replace Ubuntu with Linux Mint. I also have Windows 10 installed on my PC and I would like to keep them as well. Is there a way to replace Ubuntu, without loosing data such as installed programs and my files?

Comment: Can't you just back up your data, install the system, and copy it back?

Comment: @terdon is it that simple?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by data. You haven't given any detail here, so I am guessing you mean your files, videos, music etc. In that case,yyes, it's that simple: just take a backup, format the drive during installation and copy the files back. If you are referring to installed programs and settings, then please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: @terdon what about my programms? is there any simple way of keeping them? (not that important but I wouldn't mind keeping them)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain exactly what you would like to have. Tell us if you just want the same set of programs installed, if you want to keep your settings, if you just need to keep your personal files etc. The more detail you give us, the better people will be able to answer.

Comment: Applications may not be the same. In Ubuntu you can do this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages

Comment: @terdon I hope I explained it better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your files, and most of your settings, but you will need to reinstall the programs.

1. Make a backup of your data, everything you want to keep. After reinstalling, you can copy it back.
2. Make sure to include all dotfiles (files and directories whose name starts with a `.`) in your `$HOME` directory in your backup. Most of your settings for individual programs are stored in `$HOME/.config` or other dotfiles, so if you make a backup of these, you should be able to copy them onto the new installation and so keep your settings. This can sometimes break if there are very different versions of programs involved so the settings format might have changed, but it is very likely to work 100% if you're switching between recent versions of Ubuntu and Mint.

   If you see that some programs are behaving strangely, you can delete the corresponding dot file to get back to the default settings.
3. Export the list of installed programs and include the `installed.list` file in your backup:

   ```
    apt list --installed > installed.list
   ```
4. Install your new system, formatting the existing partition.
5. Reinstall the packages from the old system:

   ```
    sudo apt install $(cut -d'/' -f1  installed.list)
   ```
6. Copy the files from your backup, to wherever you want them. Copy the dotfiles from your old `$HOME` into the `$HOME` of the new system.

That should leave you with a new system that looks and feels almost identical to the one you left behind.

**Important caveats**: I expect this to work, but there are no guarantees. It is quite possible that different program versions will be installed so some of your settings won't be copied correctly. It is also possible that some packages will be missing because you installed them manually or because they came from non-standard repositories, or because they are not available for this version of Ubuntu etc.

The good news is that there is very little risk involved: all of your personal data is backed up, so at worst you might face a situation where you need to delete the configuration dir/file (dotfile) of a program to get it to work on the new system.

Comment: exactly what I wanted! I 'll try this as soon as possible :)

Comment: I made the backup and installed linux mint. Now I have some trouble restoring the backup. What is the best way to restore it? (it is on a seperate disk) Thanks

Comment: @Games08 I'm sorry but I have no idea what you mean. One would normally copy the files. This is the backup of your personal files, right? Things like `$HOME/my_videos`? If not, please post a new question where you can explain what you have done, what you are trying to do and how it is failing.

Comment: Am I suposed to just copy-paste the home folder? I did a backup using ubuntu's backup tool. And if yes, can I do it right now (I am on mint)?

Comment: @Games08 I don't know how this backup tool works. But yes, in theory you can copy/paste as long as it is not an image or a compressed file. I would first make a copy of all dottfiles in your new mint (`mkdir -p dotbackups && cp -rv .[a-zA-Z1-9]* dotbackups`) just in case but otherwise, yes you should be able to just copy everything over.

Comment: After a few hours it is complete. When I try ```sudo apt install $(cut -d'/' -f1  installed.list)
```, it outputs this error ```E: Unable to locate package Listing...``` and basically all the packages that were in ```installed.list```

Comment: @Games08 again, please ask a new question where you can show us exactly what you have and what you are doing.

Comment: you can go [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/651776/problem-trying-to-replace-ubuntu-with-mint) for the new post.