# Problem trying to replace Ubuntu with Mint

Tags: ubuntu, replace

I have tried replacing Ubuntu with Linux Mint. I made a file (installed.list) using  `apt list --installed > installed.list`. It created a file with the installed packages. After that, I installed linux Mint alongside Ubuntu. Then I copied the */home* folder (including the dotfiles) to Mint. I tried installing the packages again from the `installed.list` file using  `sudo apt install $(cut -d'/' -f1  installed.list)`. I get this error `E: Unable to locate package` and it's name for every package I try to install.

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package snapd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libgc1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libgc1c2:i386 libgc1c2

Package virtualbox-6.1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package Listing...
E: Unable to locate package 4kvideodownloader
E: Unable to locate package bsdextrautils
E: Unable to locate package code
E: Unable to locate package jdk-16
E: Unable to locate package libcdio19
E: Unable to locate package libdav1d4
E: Unable to locate package libdav1d4
E: Unable to locate package libdns-export1110
E: Unable to locate package libdvdread8
E: Unable to locate package libebml5
E: Unable to locate package libedataserver-1.2-25
E: Unable to locate package libffi8ubuntu1
E: Unable to locate package libffi8ubuntu1
E: Unable to locate package libfm-qt7
E: Package 'libgc1' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libgnustep-base1.27
E: Unable to locate package libgpaste13
E: Unable to locate package libhandy-1-0
E: Unable to locate package libhfstospell11
E: Unable to locate package libhogweed6
E: Unable to locate package libhogweed6
E: Unable to locate package libicu67
E: Unable to locate package libicu67
E: Unable to locate package libilmbase25
E: Unable to locate package libjson-c5
E: Unable to locate package liblibreoffice-java
E: Unable to locate package libmatroska7
E: Unable to locate package libmetacity3
E: Unable to locate package libmetrics-any-perl
E: Unable to locate package libmutter-7-0
E: Unable to locate package libnettle8
E: Unable to locate package libnettle8
E: Unable to locate package libnma-common
E: Unable to locate package libnsl-dev
E: Unable to locate package libnsl2
E: Unable to locate package libnsl2
E: Unable to locate package libnss-nis
E: Unable to locate package libnss-nis
E: Unable to locate package libnss-nisplus
E: Unable to locate package libnss-nisplus
E: Unable to locate package libopenexr25
E: Unable to locate package liborcus-parser-0.15-0
E: Unable to locate package libplacebo72
E: Unable to locate package libpoppler102
E: Unable to locate package libpoppler102
E: Unable to locate package libprotobuf-lite23
E: Unable to locate package libprotobuf23
E: Unable to locate package libqpdf28
E: Unable to locate package libqt5qmlmodels5
E: Unable to locate package libqt5qmlworkerscript5
E: Unable to locate package libreoffice-style-yaru
E: Unable to locate package libsrt1-gnutls
E: Unable to locate package libtepl-5-0
E: Unable to locate package libtest-metrics-any-perl
E: Unable to locate package libx264-160
E: Unable to locate package libx264-160
E: Unable to locate package libx265-192
E: Unable to locate package libx265-192
E: Unable to locate package libx86emu3
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.8.0-50
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.8.0-53
E: Unable to locate package microsoft-edge-beta
E: Unable to locate package rpcsvc-proto
E: Package 'snapd' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-wallpapers-groovy
E: Package 'virtualbox-6.1' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package vivaldi-stable
E: Unable to locate package wps-office
E: Unable to locate package zoom
```

installed.list:

```
Listing...
4kvideodownloader/now 4.15-1 amd64 [installed,local]
a11y-profile-manager-indicator/groovy,now 0.1.11-0ubuntu4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas/groovy,groovy,now 0.0.7+17.10.20170922-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
accountsservice/groovy-updates,groovy-security,now 0.6.55-0ubuntu13.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
acl/groovy,now 2.2.53-8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
acpi-support/groovy,now 0.143 amd64 [installed,automatic]
acpid/groovy,now 1:2.0.32-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
activity-log-manager/groovy,now 0.9.7-0ubuntu27 amd64 [installed,automatic]
adcli/groovy-updates,groovy-security,now 0.9.0-1ubuntu1.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
adduser/groovy,groovy,now 3.118ubuntu2 all [installed,automatic]
adium-theme-ubuntu/groovy,groovy,now 0.3.4-0ubuntu4 all [installed,automatic]
adwaita-icon-theme/groovy,groovy,now 3.38.0-1ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
aisleriot/groovy,now 1:3.22.9-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
alsa-base/groovy,groovy,now 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5 all [installed,automatic]
alsa-topology-conf/groovy,groovy,now 1.2.3-1 all [installed,automatic]
alsa-ucm-conf/groovy-updates,groovy-updates,now 1.2.2-1ubuntu5.2 all [installed,automatic]
alsa-utils/groovy,now 1.2.3-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
amd64-microcode/groovy,now 3.20191218.1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
anacron/groovy,now 2.3-29 amd64 [installed,automatic]
apg/groovy,now 2.2.3.dfsg.1-5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
app-install-data-partner/groovy,groovy,now 19.04 all
```

NOTE:There are more but it's almost 220.000 characters.

Original Post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/651335/replacing-ubuntu-with-linux-mint-in-dual-boot/651452#651452).

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: None of those seem to be a problem. You can still install the ones that are available. You probably don't want `snapd` on Mint anyway. Don't the rest of the packages install correctly?

Comment: @terdon Basically, my problem is that none of the packages are installed and I get the ```Unable to locate package...``` for all of them.

Comment: Please post the contents of the `installed.list` file, and either all, or a larger part of the output you get from the `apt install` command. You can use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code for clarity. If the output is too large to post, just post as much as you can.

Comment: Most (all?) of the errors seem to be about `lib*` packages. Most of those you won't need or will have been installed by other processes. Are you actually missing any programs that you want? If you don't know what a program is, you probably don't need it on your new system anyway.

Comment: @terdon the probelm is that nothing is installed and I cant install anything (using installed.list) :(

Comment: yes, but are you missing any programs you want? Is anything you need not there? Also, can you post the _full_ files (both the `installed.list` and the output of the `apt-install` somewhere like http://pastebin.com so we can look at the full info?

Comment: Hope it works. [my link](https://pastebin.com/1CKpAzJ2) :)

Comment: Great. And the output of the apt command? That's the really important one. I still think you _are_ installing many of the packages, it's just that many are giving errors. But more importantly: ***if it ain't broke, don't fix it***. Unless you are missing something, I wouldn't even bother trying to reinstall. The vast majority of things you have installed would be installed by default anyway.

Comment: I updated the output on the main post

Comment: Get rid of all the lib packages, filter the file, don't expect the same numbered lib to be present in  two unrelated pools. I see packages in there that require their own repos. You're skipping too many steps here, it's not as easy to do this as you are trying to make it out to be.

Comment: I rolled back your recent edit tagging the title with "SOLVED". If one of the answers solved your issue, consider accepting it. If you have a solution that is different from all answers, then consider adding that solution as a separate answer and accept it later. Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're skipping too many steps, first filter out all the lib files, with a few exceptions, they are dependencies of another package, and the proper version will be pulled in when the main package is installed:

```
dpkg -l | awk '$2 !~ /^lib|zoom|microsoft/ {print $2}' > installed.txt
```

This command uses dpkg -l [list packages] then takes all items that are in the second column and not starting with lib or containing zoom or microsoft and prints it out.

Then you can scan that list manually and remove any clearly  ubuntu specific packages, like ubuntu wallpapers.

Note that unless something has changed in apt, apt install maps to apt-get install, and if you try  installing a  list of packages where not all are installable, it won't work, and will simply exit because it failed. Failure is caused if anything at all in the list was not  present as a package in the pool you are using.

When I used to do such things, I'd loop through the list, and apt-get install each package in the list to avoid this issue.

```
for item in $(cat installed.txt);do apt-get --no-install-recommends install $item;done
```

You can force accept all packages and don't ask with option -y, but that's a bad idea since you want to control what actually gets installed. Basically you just hit enter each time it asks if you want to install the extra dependencies, it doesn't take that long to go through the list.

Note you want to  disable install recommends with --no-install-recommends or you end up with a horrible mess. I disable it always in /etc/apt configurations, but that's outside the scope of your question.

Also it's good to be aware that apt will itself track packages it pulled in as dependencies when installing another package, and when those are replaced during an upgrade by newer versions, those now obsolete packages are what apt-get remove will uninstall to clean the system. If you install specific numbered library versions directly using apt-get install, even if they are present in pool, apt may not offer to remove those when they are replaced by newer versions. This can lead to cluttered system.

Mint has in general old packages, you  can't expect the two package pools to actually match, though their newest version isn't as old as it will be in a  year or two.

Note that you can roughly tell how bad this will go for you  by:

```
inxi -r
```

which will list your current repositories, the more PPAs you had present, the worse it's going to go. Zero PPAs is the ideal number, but if you have a lot, it's just going to be messy, but the loop install command will avoid most of the worst parts.

I don't really use Mint so I don't remember how they do PPAs, but it's almost certain to fail since ubuntu and mint are NOT compatible, they share many packages between the Ubuntu version Mint was pulled from and the Mint you are installing, but you'll keep getting failures until you do the loop package install.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the list of unavailable packages, you need to enable `universe`. e,g: `jdk-16` is available from `universe` repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt update
```

A lot of the package can't be installed on Linux Mint because those package are only available on Ubuntu Groovy and higher and your Linux Mint release is based on Ubuntu Focal.

Comment: I still get the same error. It's really weird! I think it's because of something else and not because they are missing or something.

Comment: Note that after running this command, you also need to run `sudo apt update` to make `apt` read the changes, @Games08.

Comment: I still cant install anything :|